# Printing three rows of output given list of strings using format()

Tags: python

Hi guys I got another CSC110 question.  I'm just trying to learn the optimal way to do things. I'm sure this will be pretty easy.

Basically I need to output the names of some countries in a standard output that looks like this:

```
Afghanistan                   Albania                       Armenia
Bangladesh                    Benin                         Bhutan
Bolivia                       Burkina Faso                  Burundi
Cabo Verde                    Cambodia                      Cameroon
Central African Republic      Chad                          Comoros
Congo                         Cote D'Ivoire                 D.P.R. Of Korea
D.R. Of The Congo             Djibouti                      Egypt
El Salvador                   Eritrea                       Ethiopia
Gambia                        Georgia                       Ghana
Guatemala                     Guinea                        Guinea-Bissau
Guyana                        Haiti                         Honduras
India                         Indonesia                     Kenya
Kiribati                      Kosovo                        Kyrgyzstan
Lao People'S Dr               Lesotho                       Liberia
Madagascar                    Malawi                        Mali
Marshall Islands              Mauritania                    Micronesia (Fs Of)
Mongolia                      Morocco                       Mozambique
Myanmar                       Nepal                         Nicaragua
Niger                         Nigeria                       Pakistan
Papua New Guinea              Paraguay                      Philippines
Republic Of Moldova           Rwanda                        Samoa
Sao Tome And Principe         Senegal                       Sierra Leone
Solomon Islands               Somalia                       South Sudan
Sri Lanka                     State Of Palestine            Sudan
Swaziland                     Syrian Arab Republic          Tajikistan
Togo                          U.R. Of Tanzania: Mainland    Uganda
Ukraine                       Uzbekistan                    Vanuatu
Viet Nam                      Yemen                         Zambia
Zanzibar                      Zimbabwe
```

I have written a function that does this called table(countries). While what I have written works it doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do this.  While I don't have to use the format() function for the assignment it is something i'm most comfortable with.  Feel free to show me another way if there is a better way, but please remember this is my first programming language/class.

Here is the code I have written:

```
def table(countries):
    counter = 0 #Four counting when I've printed 3 columns
    for outer in range(len(countries)):
        print(format(countries[outer], '30'), end ='')
        counter  +=1 
        if counter  == 3:
            counter  = 0
            print() #Starts a new column
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mod and won't need another variable.

```
def table(countries):
    for outer in range(len(countries)):
      if outer%3  == 0:
        print() #Starts a new column
      print(format(countries[outer], '30'), end ='')
```

Comment: This works great but I had to move the if statement above the print statement otherwise my output would have the wrong number of columns on the first pass through.

Answer (score 2):

You can try list comprehension:

```
countries = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','dd','eeeee','fff','ggggggg']
print('\n'.join([" ".join([country.ljust(30) for country in countries[i:i+3]]) for i in range(0,len(countries),3)]))
```

which will result in:

```
aaa                            bbb                            ccc                           
dd                             eeeee                          fff                           
ggggggg
```

First of all, we separate countries into list of 3 each - `for i in range(0,len(countries),3)`

Then, we make each country from that sublist into fixed length string, filling with spaces till the length of 30 - `[country.ljust(30) for country in countries[i:i+3]]`

After, we join each sublists into one string - `" ".join(...)`

And at the end, we join each of that sublist's string into one string with End Of Line symbol - `'\n'.join(...)`

Worth noting that you are going to have trailing spaces at the end of each string - if that is unwanted, you can call rstrip() to get rid of them.

Comment: This method works when I put it in my code but is outside of my scope of knowledge at this time.  I am going to play with this though and use it to learn. Thank you